# WordPress Dynamic Content

Tags: wordpress, wp-admin

Greetings to developers community.

I'm new(beginner) on wordpress developing. I wanted to challenge myself and try to build a wordpress theme from an existing Static Website, (HTML to WordPress).

I've come across a problem or better to say I'm not having an idea of what to do on this step of development and wanted to ask for any advice or references on how to manage dynamic content on pages. What I want is: From the Dashboard if a user want to edit the content of a page how can he achieve it and do it without wanting him to go over the code. I am going to post a screenshot because I might not be cleared of what I want. 
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrcJp.jpg)

So those description how should be inserted on the page and be modified later if wanted without braking the style or model of the page?

I've tried Custom Fields but WordPress has a limit and can't add as many as I want and the list of custom fields went large.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is easily solvable with a dynamic content plugin. you can try "Dynamic Widget Content" or If>So Dynamic content. Both free and worked great for me.